# Saving CoreData to-many relationships in Swift

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, swift, relationship

I have a one-to-many relationship that looks like so,

[image: coredata model]

I've set up my model classes in a file to match:

```
import CoreData
import Foundation

class Board: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var boardColor: String
    @NSManaged var boardCustomBackground: AnyObject?
    @NSManaged var boardID: String
    @NSManaged var boardName: String
    @NSManaged var lists: NSSet
}

class List: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var listID: String
    @NSManaged var listName: String
    @NSManaged var board: Board
}
```

Because I'm fetching data from multiple JSON endpoints, I have to save my lists seperately from my boards. **What I want to do is create/update a list for a board with a matching boardID**.

Here's where I am after multiple attempts:

```
func saveList(boardID: String, listName: String, listID: String) {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Board")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "boardID like %@", boardID)
    let results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
    if results.count > 0 {
        for result in results {
            let board = result as Board
            let list = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: context) as List
            println(" want to save \(listName) in \(board.boardName)")
            board.lists.addListObject(lists)
            list.listName = listName
            list.listID = listID
        }
    }
}
```

Based on [Defining CoreData Relationships in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350264/how-to-define-coredata-relationship-in-swift) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756229/how-to-assign-coredata-many-to-many-relationship-in-swift), I tried to implement @Keenle's answer for define list objects inside a board:

```
import Foundation

extension Board {
    func addListObject(value:List) {
        var items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("lists");
        items.addObject(value)
    }

    func removeListObject(value:List) {
        var items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("lists");
        items.removeObject(value)
    }
}
```

However, I ran into the following error at `board.lists.addListObject(lists)`:
**'NSSet' does not have a member named 'addListObject'`**

Instead of `board.lists.addListObject(lists)`, I also tried `board.lists.listName = listName` as implied in this [Obj-C example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261853/saving-a-to-many-relationship), but that sadly didn't work either.

(Also, The `println` output is correctly specifying the right board and list.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please tell me , after saving how you will fetch the result ? i mean the fetch in one to many relation will be different from normal scenarios??

Comment: Can any one  please tell me , how we will fetch the records from lists of a specific boardId??

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In a one-to-many relationship, it is easier to set the "to-one" direction of the 
inverse relationships, in your case just

```
list.board = board
```

so that the extension methods are actually not needed here.

Comment: In the case of how I have my List to Board relationship set up, it looks like it's already to-one? see: http://imgur.com/uKspCtt

Comment: @Pirijan: Yes, I had seen that already in the picture in your question. Bord->List is "to-many", and List->Board is "to-one". Since these are *inverse* relationships of each other, setting one automatically updates the other. - In this case setting the List->Board relationship is a bit easier.

Comment: when I try `list.board = board`, the program fails with `Error saving context: Could not merge changes`. The conflict error list shows two boards with the same boardID, even if I've removed the db file prior to the build?

Comment: @MartinR Could you check my answer? I've just found out that you can do like that and it works for me and I think it's a good alternative.

Comment: @MartinR,  Can you please tell me , after saving how you will fetch the result ? i mean the fetch in one to many relation will be different from normal scenarios??

Answer (score 6):

You should invoke `addListObject(...)` on `board` object:

```
board.addListObject(list) // notice that we pass just one object
```

Additionaly, if you want to be able to add a set of lists to particular `board` object, you can enhance you `Board` class extension with methods that accept set of objects:

```
func addList(values: NSSet) {
    var items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("lists");
    for value in values {
        items.addObject(value)
    }
}

func removeList(values: NSSet) {
    var items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("lists");
    for value in values {
        items.removeObject(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like an uncaught exception is raised at the `var items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("lists")`. With the following error: `NSManagedObjects of entity 'Board' do not support -mutableSetValueForKey: for the property 'lists'`. Trying to figure it out now..

Comment: @Pirijan Did you ever figure out why you were getting the 'do not support -mutableSetValueForKey' error? I'm seeing the same thing and can't get around it.

Comment: I also was getting "do not support -mutableSetValueForKey" error for my project. I am newbie, so it took me for a while to find a cause.  In Model Inspector dialog for relationship field there is a field called "Type". By default it reads "To One". I selected "To Many" option there and the error gone.

Comment: @Keenle , Can you please tell me , after saving how you will fetch the result ? i mean the fetch in one to many relation will be different from normal scenarios??

Answer (score 3):

If you define:

```
@NSManaged var lists: Set<List>
```

Then you can do:

```
board.lists.insert(list)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me , after saving how you will fetch the result ? i mean the fetch in one to many relation will be different from normal scenarios??