# Saving data into a One-to-many CoreData relationship in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So I have two Core Data entities. Listing and Comment. A listing can have multiple comments so Ive created a One-to-Many relationship between them.

```
extension Listing {

    @NSManaged var listingTitle: String?
    @NSManaged var comments: NSSet?
}

extension Comment {

    @NSManaged var comment: String?
    @NSManaged var commentId: String?
    @NSManaged var rating: Int32
    @NSManaged var username: String?
    @NSManaged var listing: Listing?

}
```

However, I cant seem to figure out how to add a Comment to a Listing?

I get the data from JSON blobs and parse the values from it, so I'd have something like this:

```
let comment = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Comment", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Comment

comment.username = "User1"
```

But how do I then assign that comment to a pre-defined Listing?

Hope that made sense. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving CoreData to-many relationships in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127090/saving-coredata-to-many-relationships-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Comment` has a to-one relationship to `Listing`. Just set this relationship.

```
newComment.listing = listing
```

Comment: Ah, why didnt I think of that. However, how would I then go about retrieving all Comments assosicated with a given listing?

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
@NSManaged var comments: Set<Comment>?
```

And then you can (provided that you have an instance to a `Listing`):

```
listing.comments.insert(comment)
```