# Core data Relationship in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

I am working on iPhone application where I need to implement one to many relationship from one entity to another entity.I have export `NSManagedObject` subclass from coredata database but could not find relation accessors in core data model file like Objective-C.

Although I'm able to set data in relationship `NSSet` but this only persist while iPhone app is running. Once I kill and restart the application I didn't get entity relationship for in fetch request from core data.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  It will be great if anyone can tell me how to set data in `NSSet` relationship object. Any sample example will be a great help

Here is my core data model files. One folder can content multiple content as folder detail

```
extension FolderContent {

    @NSManaged var contentID: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var contentTitle: String?
    @NSManaged var contentType: String?
    @NSManaged var publishDate: String?
    @NSManaged var folderList: NSSet?

}

extension FolderList {

    @NSManaged var folderID: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var folderName: String?
    @NSManaged var folderDetail: NSSet?

}

func updateFolderList()
{
    // Initialize Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

    // Create Entity Description
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(FOLDER_LIST, inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

    // Configure Fetch Request
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription

    do {
        let result = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest).last as! FolderList

        let content = result.mutableSetValueForKey("folderDetail")
        content.addObject(self.getContent())

          var folderContent:FolderContent = result.folderDetail?.allObjects.first as! FolderContent
        print(folderContent.contentTitle)
        self.save()

        print(result)

    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print(fetchError)
    }

}
    func getContent()->FolderContent
{
    let folderContent = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(FOLDER_CONTENT, inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! FolderContent
    folderContent.contentID = 1
    folderContent.contentTitle = "Sandeep"
    folderContent.contentType = "Product"
    return folderContent
}
```

Comment: Did you meant that you failed to fetch the relationship records only or whole records that you persisted in database?

Comment: i failed to fetch the relationship records only.

Comment: If that case, there is a problem when you are persisting the records into core data. Kindly refer to [Saving CoreData to-many relationships in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127090/saving-coredata-to-many-relationships-in-swift). Maybe you can get some answers from there.

Comment: I have tried that without success. can you give me any sample how can i update or insert into NSSet relationship object?

Comment: a `FolderContent` have many `FolderList`; a `FolderList` is belongs to a `FolderContent`.
Is that I understand your record's relationship correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the relationship of FolderContent and FolderList is defined as

- A FolderContent have many FolderList(s)
- A FolderList only belongs to a FolderContent

---

**FolderContent**

[image]

```
extension FolderContent {
    @NSManaged var contentID: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var contentTitle: String?
    @NSManaged var contentType: String?
    @NSManaged var publishDate: String?
    @NSManaged var folderList: Set<FolderList>?
}
```

**FolderList**

[image]

```
extension FolderList {
    @NSManaged var folderID: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var folderName: String?
    @NSManaged var folderDetail: FolderContent?
}
```

Let say you want to persist the record and its relationship

```
func persistRecords() {

    // Insert the new records
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let folderContentEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("FolderContent", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let folderListEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("FolderList", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    //Create FolderContent record
    let folderContentObject = FolderContent(entity: folderContentEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    folderContentObject.setValue(CONTENTID, forKeyPath: "contentID")
    ...

    //Create FolderList record
    let folderListObject = FolderList(entity: folderListEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    folderListObject.setValue(FOLDERID, forKeyPath: "folderID")
    ...

    //Set relationship here
    folderListObject.folderDetail = folderContentObject

    do {
      try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError  {
      print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks David for your full detail.Can you please show me how to update and delete the relationship objects as well?

Comment: You can learn how to update and delete methods from here https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/02/18/core-data-cheat-sheet-for-swift-ios-developers/

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you did something like `folder.folderDetail.addObject`. With core data that won't work because core data behind the scenes is doing lots of things to maintain graph integrity. You have to use `mutableSetValueForKey` to get the set and have core data work its magic.

Comment: I have update my question. You can check how i am setting data in relation.my one question is how result.mutableSetValueForKey("folderDetail") works how core data know "folderDetail" as a mutable key? it it something we need to define somewhere?

Comment: You have to define your entities and relationships in the core data model editor. Otherwise it will never work. I think you have to take a step back and read some tutorials from the start on setting up a core data based application. Defining folderDetail in the model would be one of the first things you do.